# Unity Unique Persistant GameObject ID

Tags: unity

I was wondering if GetInstanceID() is persistant at each run?

I intend to save/load gameobjects data by their ID....I needed a persistant ID

Comment: Did you test it? What do your test results say so far?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.GetInstanceID.html

im not sure what you mean at each run? i think you mean when you press play button or run the game. unity assigns a unique id to object when its instantiates. whatever its in  editor mode or play mode. so when you delete the object and instantiate another instance of that object type, unity assigns new id to it.

if you want to give unique ids on play mode you can do it in the code. there are algorithms that generate unique strings for you

Comment: This answer would be better if it suggested such an algorithm to use, rather than just asserting that they exist.